# Lottie Animation not working correctly in app layout

Tags: android, lottie

Lottie Animation not working correctly.

xml file

```
 <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/check_in_anim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_fileName="tenor.json"
                app:lottie_loop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

activity

```
  LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.check_in_anim);
        lottieAnimationView.playAnimation();
```

[image]

my Lottie file: https://lottiefiles.com/6863-tenor

Comment: You have to add your animation in xml also. Check my answer. It should help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your lottie json in res/raw and add this to your xml

```
app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/your_animation"
```

Like this

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/check_in_anim"
                app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/your_animation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_fileName="tenor.json"
                app:lottie_loop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

For more details. you can look official documentation [here](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android)

Comment: can you share what are you getting after doing this

Comment: animation well play but half animation play and half animation well not play correctly like above image

Comment: I have also attached official documentation. It may help

Comment: i follow your attached documentation. but does't work i think animation file was large then not working properly. please you can try my lottie animation if work fine then replay me. thank u.

Answer (score 1):

add a Lottie.json file in your **res/raw** folder
[image]

Now use this on your tag -->

```
app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/your_animation"
```

Full xml code ---->

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/check_in_anim"
                app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/your_animation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_fileName="tenor.json"
                app:lottie_loop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```